# WifiManager.disconnect() deprecated in Android Q

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, disconnect

In Android Q and above (**API >= 29**), the [WifiManager.disconnect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#disconnect()) method has been **deprecated**.

What would be the solution to disconnect from the Wi-Fi network in Android 10 and above?

I have implemented the next code, yet it fails always returning:
[STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_REMOVE_INVALID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR_REMOVE_INVALID).

I guess the reason for the failure could be that [removeNetworkSuggestions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E)) maybe is expected to work in conjunction with [addNetworkSuggestions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List%3Candroid.net.wifi.WifiNetworkSuggestion%3E)), but I don't need to add any networks, on the contrary, to disconnect from the active one.

```
public final class WifiUtils {

    private static final String TAG = "WifiUtils";

    public static void disconnect(final Context context) {

        // Sanity check
        if (context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // Without the <Fine location> permission the returned SSID is always: '<unknown ssid>'.
            // Note: The <Coarse location> permission is not enough.
            Log.e(WifiUtils.TAG, "Missing <ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION> permission. Required to obtain the Wifi SSID.");
            return;
        }

        final WifiManager manager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isWifiEnabled())
            return;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

            final WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();

            if (wifiInfo == null) {
                Log.w(WifiUtils.TAG, "Failed to get connection details.");
                return;
            }

            final String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ssid)) {
                Log.e(WifiUtils.TAG, "Unable to resolve Wifi SSID.");
            } else {
                Log.i(WifiUtils.TAG, "Resolved Wifi SSID: " + ssid);

                final List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

                suggestions.add(new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                        .setSsid(wifiInfo.getSSID())
                        .build());

                final int status = manager.removeNetworkSuggestions(suggestions);
                Log.d(WifiUtils.TAG, "Wifi disconnection status result: " + status);
            }
        } else {
            manager.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the required permissions in the manifest, granted at runtime:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @HarshBhikadia Seems in Android Q and above developers are not allowed anymore to connect / disconnect the Wifi programmatically. In the next issue Google states this is the new expected behavior: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128554616#comment23

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while. Best thing to do is have the Android System take care of it with the following intent.

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY));`

This will show a number of WiFi SSIDs around the user's location and they are able to pick one of the WiFis to connect to.